# Open diode, find load voltage

Tags: voltage, diodes

Why is the load voltage a little less than 15 V when the diode is open in Fig. 1.2?[image]

Is 14,3V because the source voltage is 15V and  0.7  the diode voltage so 15-0,7=14,3V?

Comment: do you see any other components in the circuit?

Comment: only what appears in the photo

Comment: let me rephrase my question ... what components do you see in the circuit? ... please list them

Comment: 100kOhm resistor is the load, 1kOhm resistor, a diode 1N4007 and and source 15V

Comment: I see that your question has been answered

Comment: @EviPapanagiotou where are you studying EE?

Answer (score 2):

First, let's define what's what: the 100kOhm resistor is the load, the 1kOhm resistor is a series resistance.

When the diode is in the circuit, the load is parallel to it: the voltage on the diode and the load are the same. The load voltage then is 0.7V.

When the diode is "open", as your teacher/textbook uses means it, it's short for "open circuit". Like opening a switch. It's gone. Not there. Absent. Removed. Disappeared. Whatever you call it, "open" as relates to a component in such simple circuit analysis is just synonym for "the component is not there".

Without the diode, you have a simple resistive divider. 1/101 of the voltage is dropped across the series resistor. The remaining 100/101 of the voltage is dropped across the load. The load voltage with diode absent is thus \${100 \over 101}\cdot 15{\rm\,V} = 14.851{\rm\,V}\$. Not 14.3V.

Comment: @evi-papanagiotou: Note that many beginners use "Open" to mean conducting/passing current (like an open tap allows water to pass).  In electronics, an open circuit or open component DOES NOT allow current to pass.